# Merge two variable values to get a new variable name (not value)

Tags: php

is possible in php to merge the first variable value with the second variable value to get a new variable name (not value).

```
$1 = test
$2 = 5
//do magic results in new variable name eg. $($1+$2)
$test5 = true
```

So if $2 is dynamic we get a dynamic variable name, not a dynamic value. The value "true" is just an example value. I don't know If it is possible, because I'm completely new to PHP and found nothing by searching.

Comment: Please note that `$1 = test` is invalid in PHP. Variables cannot begin with a number and `test` should be either a string or a constant so define it properly. Kindly update your question.

Comment: See variable variables: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php . assuming `$a = test; $b = 5`; then `${$a.$b} = true; echo $test5;` displays `1`  (or true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use {} after the $ sign to interpret the inner content as the variable name.

```
$a = "test";
$b = 5;

${$a . $b} = "new value";
echo "test5 = " . $test5; // prints test5 = new value
```

See [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) page for more details.

Comment: Thank you Brian and all others. This is realy cool. Well I didn't guess this would work so easy.  I've got to go deeper now in this language.